# Can we call a method in other method in constructor class?

Tags: java, methods, constructor

For example, I created a class Pizza which have method pizzaCodes() and pizzaSizes(). I used pizzaSizes() method (which take input and return the value) in pizzaCodes() method. The codes for pizzaCodes() are like below:

```
public String pizzaCodes(){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        System.out.println("Choose your pizza: ");
        code = sc.next().charAt(0);
        
    switch(code){
        
        case 'A', 'a':
            System.out.println("Pizza: " + pizzaCode[0]);
            System.out.println("Choose size(R/L): ");
            pizzaSizes(size); // pizzaSizes() method used in pizzaCodes() method.
            
            if(pizzaSize == 'R'){
                dPizza = "Chicken Delight: Regular";
                price2 = price[0];
            }else{
                dPizza = "Chicken Delight: Large";
                price2 = price[3];
            }
            System.out.println("Quantity?");
            quantity = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        case 'B', 'b':
            
            System.out.println("Pizza: " + pizzaCode[1]);
            System.out.println("Choose size(R/L): ");
            pizzaSizes(size); // pizzaSizes() method used in pizzaCodes() method.
            if(pizzaSize == 'R'){
                dPizza = "Beef Pepperoni: Regular";
                price2 = price[1];
            }else{
                dPizza = "Beef Pepperoni: Large";
                price2 = price[4];
            }
            System.out.println("Quantity?");
            quantity = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        case 'C', 'c':
            
            System.out.println("Pizza: " + pizzaCode[2]);
            System.out.println("Choose size(R/L): ");
            pizzaSizes(size); // pizzaSizes() method used in pizzaCodes() method.
            if(pizzaSize == 'R'){
                dPizza = "Cheese Bomb: Regular";
                price2 = price[2];
            }else{
                dPizza = "Cheese Bomb: Large";
                price2 = price[5];
            }
            System.out.println("Quantity?");
            quantity = sc.nextInt();
            break;
        case 'D', 'd':
            dPizza = "Super Deals";
            System.out.println("Pizza: " + pizzaCode[3]);
            System.out.println("Choose size(R/L): ");
            pizzaSizes(size); // pizzaSizes() method used in pizzaCodes() method.
            System.out.println("Quantity?");
            quantity = sc.nextInt();
            break;
    }
    
    total = price2 * quantity;
    totPrice = total + totPrice;
    
    if(totPrice > 50){ // if else for applying discount
        newPrice = totPrice - 20;
        System.out.println("Discount applied");
        System.out.println("Total amount :RM" + String.format("%.2f", newPrice));
    }else{
        newPrice = totPrice;
        System.out.println("No discount applied");
        System.out.println("Total amount :RM" + String.format("%.2f", newPrice));
    }

    return dPizza;
}
```

And this is pizzaSizes() code:

```
public String[] pizzaSizes(String[] size){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    pizzaSize = sc.next().charAt(0);
    
    if(pizzaSize == 'R'||pizzaSize == 'r'){
        System.out.println("Size: " + size[0]);
    }else{
        System.out.println("Size: " + size[1]);
    }
    
    return size;
}
```

I expecting an error since I learned to call a method inside main method and plus I'm new in java coding but it's working perfectly fine. I'm actually curious does it actually against java rules.

Comment: what is a "*method created in other method*" ? And what error are you expecting? Why are you expecting it?

Comment: you can't create a method inside another method

Comment: @user16320675 i mean to call another method inside other method if that make any sense

Comment: what is `constructor class` ?

Comment: @user16320675 ye i edited the question and as I'm saying I'm new and kinda dumb in coding. I'm sorry and thank you

Comment: @Antoniossss constructor is special method to initialize objects

Comment: @user16320675 i know constructor is NOT a method. The code above is method INSIDE a constructor class Pizza and yes class constructor. Sorry

Comment: Calling methods from other methods is one of the essential building blocks of Java and almost every other modern language. So if this weren't possible all those languages wouldn't make sense. Also, a constructor _is_ a method of sorts, it just has specific properties. As such you _can_ call methods from a constructor.

Comment: @Antoniossss oh sorry I meant constructor class. I'm sorry.

Comment: @sakif there is no such thing

Comment: @Antoniossss ah yes constructor of a class. Thanks for correcting me